# Radio button and Option value Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select the second radio button in the Cases Filed category of the following URL: https://dockets.justia.com/

The radio button saying "between" ..<Date1> and <Date 2>

The relevant portion of the source code:

```
     <div class="row horizontal">
        <span class="row-label">Cases Filed:</span>
          <span class="row-fields">

    <div>
   <input type="radio" name="cases" id="casesmostrecent" value="mostrecent"         checked=&quot;checked&quot;>
 <span>All Dates</span>
 </div>
 <div>
 <input type="radio" name="cases" id="casesbetween" value="between" >
 <span>Between</span>

       <span>
```

Further I want to know how to fill the dates in the "option value"...

Code portion for the same URL:

```
 <select name="min-day">
 <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option> 
   <option value="3">3</option> 
  <option value="4">4</option> 
    <option value="5">5</option>
```